# Template function accepting callable functors with X parameters

Tags: c++, templates, functor, seh

I'm writing a hosted C++ program that runs user-written C-code compiled on the fly. It's absolutely vital that certain typical exceptions are caught from the C-code and processed/ignored.
To do this, I'm calling the C code from within a structured exception handling block. Due to the nature and semantics of this block (and where it's called from), I've separated the actual calling to it's own function:

```
    template <typename ret_type, class func>
        static ret_type Cstate::RunProtectedCode(func function) {
            ret_type ret = 0;
            __try {
                ret = function();
            }
            __except(ExceptionHandler(GetExceptionCode(), ExceptionStatus::CSubsystem)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "First chance exception in C-code.\n");
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Which works nicely as it should like so:

```
        RunProtectedCode<int>(entry);
```

But is it possible to shape this so i can call functions with variable amounts of parameters - maybe through some use of exotic functors (only requirement is obviously that it can't have a destructor)? I'm using MSVC++ 2010.

Comment: There are variadic templates, but I'm afraid they're not supported in VS 2010.

Comment: Won't mind upgrading to VS2012 if it can be accomplished there. Can you make a code example?

Comment: Sadly, VS2012 also doesn't support variadic templates.

Comment: @Xeo, Very true, but there's still the CTP for now if that's permissible.

Comment: @chris: Too bad the CTP contains what we call *buggyadics* :/

Comment: In C++11 (which in this case VS2012 approximates well enough) this can be easy, just pass a lambda `[&](){foo(arg1, arg2, arg3);}` to `RunProtectedCode` in place of the function you'd normally pass, and the call to `foo` is done when the lambda is evaluated.

Comment: Uhhh that lambda solution is perfect, no change to code or IDE needed :) thanks a lot, if you want a tick, you can write it in a answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++11 you can achive this with variadic tempaltes.

```
template <typename ret_type, class func, typename... Args>
    static ret_type Cstate::RunProtectedCode(func function, Args&&... args) {
        ret_type ret = 0;
        __try {
            ret = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        __except(ExceptionHandler(GetExceptionCode(), ExceptionStatus::CSubsystem)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "First chance exception in C-code.\n");
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And you can call it like

```
RunProtectedCode<int>(entry2, 1, 2);
RunProtectedCode<int>(entry3, 1, "a", 3);
```

---

You can simplify it (*kind of*) by using std::function instead.

```
template <class func, typename... Args>
    static 
    typename func::result_type Cstate::RunProtectedCode(func function, Args&&... args) {
        typename func::result_type ret = typename func::result_type();
        __try {
            ret = function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        __except(ExceptionHandler(GetExceptionCode(), ExceptionStatus::CSubsystem)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "First chance exception in C-code.\n");
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And you can call it like

```
std::function<int(int,int,int)> entry_f = entry;
RunProtectedCode(entry_f,1,2,3);
```

Comment: As of C++17 the idiomatic way to invoke callable objects is by using `std::invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind all arguments to your function making it effectively 0-ary functor, e.g. using `std::bind` (available in VC2010) or `boost::bind` (I prefer this one because VC implementation contains broken `std::cref`). Binding can be done in overloaded function before passing to `RunProtectedCode`, e.g. something like this:

```
template<typename R>
R(*f)() wrap(R(*f)())
{
    return f;
}

template<typename R, typename A>
boost::function<R(A)> wrap(R(*f)(), A a)
{
    return boost::bind(f, a);
}

template<typename R, typename A1, typename A2>
boost::function<R(A1, A2)> wrap(R(*f)(), A1 a1, A2 a2)
{
    return boost::bind(f, a1, a2);
}
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that in VS2010, `std::bind` copy constructs its arguments something like 10 times. `boost::bind` and VS2012's `std::bind` behave better in that regard as well.